# How to average of n vectorized vectors with tdfid vectorizer.transform?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

First I vectorized all the documents with `docs_vectorized = vectorizer.fit_transform(docs['content'])` then let's assume I have different vectorized vectors:

```
df = docs[docs['category'] == 'category1']
a = vectormaker.transform(df['content'])
df = docs[docs['category'] == 'category2']
b = vectormaker.transform(df['content'])
```

How can I make a new vector that is average of a and b keeping the same type? Assuming that both are csr_matrix.

Comment: Why do want to do it? I can't think of any interesting use of this.

Comment: So we are developing a project for a course and we have to do pretty much profile based retrieval, we've a set of documents which are labeled in 5 categories and if a user likes 2 or 3 categories, we have to get the tfidf vector of those categories and get the average vector. (we've managed to solve this) This was the suggestion our professor made.  Do you think there's a better approach?

Comment: I'm not sure that this will give the expected results, you might end up with something which is similar to none of the averaged categories. I would probably rather try to obtain the tfidf similarity scores first, and then do some reranking based on the categories.